# Binding an element's property in MainWindow to a property in an embedded UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my UserControl I have a DataGrid and a Button. I can easily bind the IsEnabled property of the Button to the SelectedItems.Count property of the DataGrid.

For example, in my UserControl I have...

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" />
```

However, I'm wanting to do the same with a Button in my MainWindow where I also have the same UserControl embedded.

I would like to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=MyDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count}" />
```

Is there a way to do this purely in XAML or do I need to create a property in my ViewModel that reflects the SelectedItems.Count property of the DataGrid and bind that to my Button in the MainWindow?

Thanks!

Comment: Your UserControl should expose appropriate dependency properties, e.g. a SelectedItems property or perhaps only a readonly SelectedItemsCount. Do not expose its UI elements as properties.

Answer (score 0):

Define public property in UserControl (to keep selected items), and bind it to SelectedItem of datagrid, 
Now you will be able to get public property in main window by ElementName and XPath or Path.